# error in if condition even i enter code correctly in c programming

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

int main()
{
     int check;
     int enter[7];
     int i,j;

     printf("enter any 7 number to be stored");
     for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
           scanf("%d" ,&enter[i]);
     printf("\nenter any number to check:");
     scanf("%d" ,&check);
     for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
     {
           if (enter[i]=check)
           {
                printf("your entry is valid");
                exit(0);
           }
           else if(enter[6]!=check)
           {
                 printf("your entry is not valid");
                 exit(0);
           }
           else
                 continue;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

this executes without error but dont work correctly .. always prints out the input is valid.... even i enter the number which is not in array :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is assignment, not equality:

```
if (enter[i]=check)
```

Change to:

```
if (enter[i] == check)
```

Additionally, always check the result of input operations:

```
if (1 != scanf("%d" ,&enter[i]))
{
    /* Handle invalid value. */
}
```

to ensure subsequent code is operating on variables that have been assigned values.

Comment: i made it as: if (enter[i]== check) . but it started printing " your entry is not valid " . so then what should i do

Comment: @RahulSubedi, check return value of `scanf()` to ensure something was read and print out the values prior to the `==` to see what the actual values are.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if (enter[i]=check)
```

does not do what you expect. You probably meant

```
if (enter[i]==check)
```

The assignment is valid C, but instead of checking for equality, it sets `enter[i]` equal `check`, and *then* checks the value of `check` for being zero. If it is non-zero, the condition succeeds, regardless of the initial value of `enter[i]`. If the `check` is zero, then the condition fails, - again, regardless of the initial value of `enter[i]`. This is a very common mistake; many compilers issue warnings to alert you to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator, not equality at all. Doing:

```
if (enter[i]=check)
```

`enter[i]` will take the value `check`, and then it will check whether `enter[i]` is nonzero.

```
if (enter[i] == check)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter[i]==check)// 2 for compare
```

Answer (score 0):

proper usage of = is assignment operator whilst == is testing the equality

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<process.h>
int main()

{
int check;
int enter[7];
int i,j;
printf("enter any 7 number to be stored");
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    scanf("%d" ,&enter[i]);

}
printf("\nenter any number to check:");
scanf("%d" ,&check);
for (i=0;i<7;i++)
{
   // printf("\nvalue of i is %d\n" ,i);
    if (check==enter[i])
    {
        printf("your entry is valid");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(enter[i]!=check && i==6)
    {

        printf("your entry is not valid");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    continue;
}
return 0;
}

 now i got it all right . thanks :)
```